# change "ballooning" to "balloon"?

Tags: discussion, tags

[ballooning](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ballooning) is the only aircraft class for which the tag is the activity rather than the aircraft.

I think it should be [balloons](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/balloons) to parallel [gliders](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gliders) [helicopters](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/helicopters) [airplanes](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/airplanes) etc

and i do mean changed, and not just made a synonym. we don't have [gliding](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gliding) and [soaring](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soaring)

Comment: [thanks for the great edit @federico]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I agree that it should be the name of the class, and not the activity.

Only a small nitpick, though.
We do not have [gliders](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gliders) [helicopters](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/helicopters) [airplanes](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/airplanes), we have the singular forms: [glider](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/glider) [helicopter](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/helicopter) [airliner](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/airliner). And thus I think it should be [balloon](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/balloon).

Comment: @rbp apparently we should proof-read each other's posts :P :D

Comment: apparently we do! it takes a village!

Comment: Do *blimp* questions get assigned the *balloon* tag?

Comment: @RockPaperLizard I don't see why not, but you could ask another question here on meta.

Comment: Thanks.  Done.  See: http://meta.aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/2980/do-blimp-questions-get-assigned-the-new-balloon-tag