# Do *blimp* questions get assigned the new *balloon* tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Is it best to assign [blimp](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blimp) questions the [new](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2974/1467) [balloon](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/balloon) tag, or better to create a new tag for them?

Comment: also relevant: http://meta.aviation.stackexchange.com/a/354/1467

Comment: We already have an [airship tag](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/airship), is there any reason it isn't suitable?

Comment: @Pondlife Actually, airship is better than blimp.  Thanks for pointing it out.  Perhaps blimp can be added as a synonym tag to airship.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If we're logically following the discussion [here](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2974/change-ballooning-to-balloon) then [blimp](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blimp) would most closely correspond to the class tag [airship](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/airship).

The key difference is balloons don't have their own means of horizontal propulsion (they climb or descend to ride an appropriate wind), where blimps/airships *do* have their own horizontal propulsion.

Unless there's an outcry against it I'd be in favor of merging [blimp](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blimp) into [airship](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/airship) and leaving a synonym.

Comment: I like everything you said and agree. :-)

Comment: As of this afternoon there were no [tag:blimp] questions, but I've created the synonym anyway since I'm sure people will use "blimp" at some point in the future. There is an edge case here where someone is specifically asking about a *blimp* (a pressure airship) rather than a *dirigible* (rigid or semi-rigid airship with a supporting structure), but they're all properly "airships" anyway, so we can torch that Hindenberg when it files in.